# Make compound geo hashtag mongodb index format while also specifying bits etc

Tags: mongodb

I want make geo Hastag mongodb But i don't know format properly

this is format i read from site mongo:

```
db.places.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d"} , { bits : 26 } )
```

I want add some field index but the same index with geo hashtag.

Something like 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing

However, I want the index to be compound indexes?

Should I do

```
db.tablebusiness.ensureIndex( {"LongitudeLatitude" : "2d", 
                               "indexContents" : 1, 
                               "Prominent" : -1 } , 
                              { bits : 22 } )
```

If I do that, how does mongodb knows that bits:22 is an option for LongitudeLatitude part of the index?

Also what's the equivalent for haystack indexing?

```
db.tablebusiness.ensureIndex( {"LongitudeLatitude" : "geoHaystack", 
                               "indexContents" : 1, 
                               "Prominent" : -1 } , 
                              { bits : 22 ,bucketsize: .2} )
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntactical thing. Your assumption above is correct. Since mongoDB supports only one geo-spatial index, and you specify that the LongitudeLatitude part of the index is geospatial with the "2d" index flag ( as opposed to 1 for ascending and -1 for descending), it knows that the bits parameters being passed to ensureIndex corresponds with the LongitudeLatitude field.

Same for Haystack indexing.